How to stop clean up scheduler in Azure SQL DB CDC
I have requirement where i need to perform Audit of data for that i have planned to use Azure DB change data capture(CDC).
In Azure CDC it works on scheduler unlike on premise where SQL Server Agent which handles tracking of data and cleanup for cdc.
Now, scenario is i want to keep my audit data as it and disable cleanup service on Azure how can i do that?
Thanks in advance

Dropping the cleanup job entry stops the cleanup job. You can use the sp_cdc_drop_job procedure to drop the cleanup job and you can add it back with the sp_cdc_add_job procedure as needed. You can query the cdc.cdc_jobs table to get information about CDC jobs.
EXEC sys.sp_cdc_drop_job @job_type = N'cleanup';

